# WiX / MSI: How to update an registered shell extension on Windows XP

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an application which registers a Windows Explorer shell extension.

The application's installer is developed using WIX.

I remove the old product before I install the new:

```
RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize"
```

The problem is that this fails on Windows XP. Not suprising as the extension is in use by Windows Explorer. Of course it happens quite often that the Windows Explorer has no default window, so the Files-In-Use Dialog does not show up as well.

So my big question: What's the best way to update Windows Explorer shell extensions using WiX?

Is there any better solution than [ForceReboot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

An Idea: I wrote an NSIS installer a while ago, where I solved a similiar problem by renaming the old extension. But that's not possible with WiX, is it?

Note: I'm asking for Windows XP, as on Vista or above the restart manager does a good job.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule `RemoveExistingProducts` immediately before `InstallFinalize`, and an `InstallExecute` action immediately before `RemoveExistingProducts`. Not only is this more efficient, it is also able to replace the file (if not hard locked) and schedule the old file for deletion upon reboot, or to schedule the new file to copy over the old after a reboot (both using PendingFileRename).